# Tooltip position using data-for

Tags: kendo-ui

I have an email input with a button after.

I was trying to get the validation tooltip to display after the button, instead of after the email input.  Followed the documentation on Kendo and added the span below, still no difference.

No quite sure where to look.

```
            <div class="input-append">
          <input type="email" class="k-textbox" id="emailAddr" name="EmailAddr" autofocus placeholder="type email address ..." validationMessage="Invalid email format" data-bind="value: emailAddress"/>              
          <button class="btn" type="button" data-bind="click: addShare"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
          <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="EmailAddr"></span>              
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got the behavior I was after was to add CSS float left to the email and button, that made the validation tooltip appear to the right of the button.  I removed the span data-for altogether.